# When should I use "is", and when "does"?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

I know this is really basic, and I know the answer internally, I just find that I can't articulate it. When would you use "is", and when is "does" more appropriate?

E.g. "The sun is green", vs "The computer does work".

I'm looking for a really concise and easy to remember explanation, not for the entire theory of tenses.

Comment: "Is" and "does" are not tenses of the same verb. This isn't a real question.

Comment: @simchona - I don't understand why you consider it "not a real question", even if it contains some factual errors.

Comment: You are asking for an explanation between two verbs, which may be considered overly broad for this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your two examples, the usage can be pretty clear from the meaning. "Does" in your example, is used to mean that the computer "actually" works. Where as "is" is used to make a declaration.

Thus, if you were to say something is "actually" doing something, use "does" :

> The cat does scratch with its lame leg!
>   The bird does talk.

"Does" can also be used for emphasis:

> He does work hard.

"Does" can also be the singular of "do" :

> He does medicine at college at the moment.

"Is" is used when making a declarative statement :

> The computer is working
>   The apple is red
>   The cat is fierce.

I hope that contrasts the two pretty much.

Comment: how about this case ? "Is EclipePDT having its own internal webserver ? " or "Does EclipePDT having its own internal webserver ? "

Answer (score 1):

You use "is" to describe something's nature or status. The condition is passive. The Sun's condition is green. It is not necessarily changing or acting in any way.

You use "does" to describe what action something is performing. The action is active. The computer is performing work.

Comment: I think your answer brings up the point that "is" vs "does" may also be general reference.